# SQL to Linq-to-SQL Conversion

Tags: linq-to-sql

[image: Database]

Can any body help me to convert the following SQL query in LinqToSql syntax. It involves Multiple tables from my tables. I am not sure if I am using correct Query Type. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
public IQueryable<tblCourseNeededHours>(int departmentId, string semester)
{
    return from = 
        "SELECT tblCourseNeededHours.Semester, tblCourseNeededHours.NeededHoursPerWeek, 
                tblCourseNeededHours.AssignToInstituteAdministrator, 
                tblCourseNeededHours.Freezed, tblCourse.CourseName, 
                tblInstitute.InstituteName, tblDepartment.DepartmentName
         FROM tblCourseNeededHours 
             INNER JOIN tblCourse ON 
                 tblCourseNeededHours.CourseID = tblCourse.CourseID 
             INNER JOIN tblInstitute ON 
                 tblCourse.InstituteID = tblInstitute.InstituteID 
             INNER JOIN tblDepartment ON 
                 tblInstitute.DepartmentID = tblDepartment.DepartmentID";
}
```

Comment: You do not seem to use the parameters anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you have proper foreign keys in your database you can just do

```
Var x = from nh in db.tblCourseNeededHours
        select nh.Semester, nh.xxxx, nh.tblCourse.CourseName, 
        nh.tbCourse.tblInstitute.CourseName
```

and so forth.

No need to do any of the inner joins yourself. That is the beauty of Linq2Sql.

Comment: var x = from nh in db.tblCourseNeededHours select nh.Semester, nh.tblCourse.CourseName, nh.tbCourse.tblInstitute.CourseName, nh.tblDepartment.DepartmentName where nh.tblCourseNeededHours.Semester ==semester && nh.tblCourse.tblInstitute.DepartmentID == id;
            return x;     (but still error), i am including my database diagram for ur reference